# Parse SQL with REGEX to find Physical Update

Tags: sql, regex

I've spent a bit of time trying to bend regex to my will but its beaten me.

Here's the problem, for the following text...

```
--to be matched
UPDATE dbo.table
UPDATE TOP 10 PERCENT dbo.table

--do not match
UPDATE #temp
UPDATE TOP 10 PERCENT #temp
```

I'd like to match the first two updates statements and not match the last two update statements. So far I have the regex...

```
UPDATE\s?\s+[^#]
```

I've been trying to get the regex to ignore the TOP 10 PERCENT part as its just gets in the way. But I haven't been successful.

Thanks in advance.

I'm using .net 3.5

Comment: Why not just use `where text not like '%#%'`?

Comment: How do you plan on using this regex?

Comment: Search SQL statements and stored procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're trying to parse real SQL syntax (looks like SQL Server) so I've tried something that is more suitable for that (rather than just detecting the presence of `#`).

You can try regex like:

```
UPDATE\s+(TOP.*?PERCENT\s+)?(?!(#|TOP.*?PERCENT|\s)).*
```

It checks for `UPDATE` followed by optional `TOP.*?PERCENT` and then by something that is not `TOP.*?PERCENT` and doesn't start with `#`. It doesn't check just for the presence of `#` as this may legitimately appear in other position and not mean a temp table.

Comment: `[^(#|TOP.*?PERCENT|\s)]` I believe you mixed up some concepts here :/ What is this supposed to do? And why the `\s`?

Comment: @Robin Well, I'm trying to make it more suitable to the context of maching SQL queries. Your regex will not match, e.g. `UPDATE [a#temp]` even though `[a#temp]` is a physical table. `\s` is necessary in my approach to cater for multiple spaces.

Comment: I do praise your intent, but `[^...]` is a negative character class: it stands for "one character, any one except those inside it". So `[^|TOP|]` is the same as `[^|PTO]` and means a character that's not `|` or `P` or etc. Maybe you were thinking of a negative look ahead?

Comment: @Robin You got me :) Yes, you're right about that. I updated my regex to use negative look ahead.

Comment: Hi Szymon this is the most promising solution. I tried to simplifier it a little. So `UPDATE\s+(TOP\s.+?\sPERCENT\s)?#` actually does the exact opposite of what I'm looking for. However `UPDATE\s+(TOP\s.+?\sPERCENT\s)?[^#]` doesn't do what I expected. Could you tell me if look aheads are expensive?

Comment: They are not very expensive. They just try to match the next character(s) (for look-ahead assertions) so it's pretty much similar to "normal" matching.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want a regex to interact with SQL code, not actually querying a database?

You can use a negative look ahead to check if the line has `#temp`:

```
(?m)^(?!.*#temp).*UPDATE
```

`(?!...)` will fail the whole match if what's inside it matches, `^` matches the beginning of the line when combined with the `m` modifier. `(?m)` is the inline version of this modifier, as I don't know how/where you plan on using the regex.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/vL3rR1).

Comment: Robin, is the look ahead greedy? I've not even seen the `m` modifier before. Plus I don't need to match the begining of the line, I'm searching SQL code, so the update could be anywhere on the line.

Comment: @sqlconsumer.net: But you still want to check the solution line by line, right? Updated so that `UPDATE` doesn't have to be at the beginning. `(?m)` is just a way of setting the `m` flag, the flag setting can change depending on which function you use to call the regex. Feel free to remove it and set it otherwise if you want. The `.*` in the lookahead is greedy but that doesn't matter here (`.` doesn't match newlines), why?

Answer (score 0):

@Robin's solution is much better but in case you needed regex with some simplier mechanisms employed I give you this:

```
UPDATE\s+(TOP\s+10\s+PERCENT\s+)?[a-z\.]+
```

Comment: Definitely works, but I think Szymon's is more generic. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

sqlconsumer, here's a fully functioning C# .NET program. Does it do what you're looking for?

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program {
static void Main() {

string s1 = "UPDATE dbo.table";
string s2 = "UPDATE TOP 10 PERCENT dbo.table";
string s3 = "UPDATE #temp";
string s4 = "UPDATE TOP 10 PERCENT #temp";
string pattern = @"UPDATE\s+(?:TOP 10 PERCENT\s+)?dbo\.\w+";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s1, pattern) );
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s2, pattern));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s3, pattern));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.IsMatch(s4, pattern));
Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
Console.ReadKey();
} // END Main
} // END Program
```

**The Output:**

```
True
True
False
False
```